# How to display only latest post in laravel 5.2 and that too without html <p> tag?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, summernote

I want to display only latest post(or status) posted by the user. The problem is all the posts are displayed with a `<p>` tag. I am taking input in summernote editor.

What I am doing is:

```
 $accounts=Account::orderBy('updated_at','')->get();
```

I am outputting it in my view file as :  {{$account->estado}}

Comment: Are the posts stored with a `<p>` tag in the database or is that inserted on rendering?

Comment: If the posts are stored with a <p> tag, you'll have to use strip_tags or something similar to get rid of them, or store the strings without the tags.

Comment: If your problem is that `<p>` is displayed in the page then you should use `{!! $account->estado !!}` to display the HTML raw. As I see it there really isn't enough information to answer the question

Comment: @apokryfos Ty it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will get latest account and limit to certain no as you want,
for example get latest 5 post.

```
$accounts=Account::orderBy('updated_at','desc')->limit(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the html tags you can use: [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
echo strip_tags("Hello <b>world!</b>");
```

Results:

> Hello world!

And to get only the `$x` last account(s):

```
$x = 5;
$accounts = Account::orderBy('updated_at','desc')
    ->limit($x)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last input by date using this:

```
$accounts=Account::orderBy('updated_at','desc')->first();
```

And you can use ->select('field1, field2'); in the query too, if you need to be selective in the fields to retrieve.

You can find more info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

To get rid of the tags you can use strip_tags or similar.

Or store the strings with the tags removed.

Here is some information about blade templates: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade

Answer (score 0):

```
$accounts=Account::orderBy('updated_at','')->first();
```

This will only take the first element of your request.